# Py(Spark) largest order and total order

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate, data-wrangling

I have data where I have customer id, product id and total ordered amount. In some cases one customer can order multiple product or vice versa.

- Now I want to sum based on customer id and product they ordered.
- This part goes OK for me.
- But at the same time I want to have information largest order placed.

| cust_id | prod_id | order_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4726050 | 805300 | 6000 |
| 4726050 | 805300 | 12000 |
| 4733572 | 413800 | 25000 |
| 4733968 | 415400 | 4000 |
| 4733981 | 798400 | 8000 |
| 4735096 | 412200 | 14000 |
| 4735096 | 410600 | 32000 |
| 4735096 | 414200 | 15000 |
| 4735096 | 410600 | 7000 |
| 4735200 | 470600 | 5000 |

I tried following code in `pyspark`.

```
order_df.createOrReplaceTempView('order_df')
order_agg_df= spark.sql("""
                        SELECT cust_id, prod_id,
                        MAX(order_amount) as `largest_order`,
                        SUM(order_amount) as `total_order
                        FROM 
                           order_df
                         GROUP BY 1, 2
                         """)
display(order_agg_df)
```

The problem I am having I get for `largest_order` order I get total `total_order`.

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `list` of expressions using `sum` and `max` on your variable, and unpack that in pysparks [`GroupedData.agg`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.agg.html):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

expr = [F.sum(F.col("order_amount")).alias("total_order"),
        F.max(F.col("order_amount")).alias("largest_order")]
```

Prints back:

```
>>> df.groupBy(["cust_id","prod_id"]).agg(*expr).show(truncate=False)

+-------+-------+-----------+-------------+
|cust_id|prod_id|total_order|largest_order|
+-------+-------+-----------+-------------+
|4735200|470600 |5000       |5000         |
|4735096|410600 |39000      |32000        |
|4726050|805300 |18000      |12000        |
|4733981|798400 |8000       |8000         |
|4733968|415400 |4000       |4000         |
|4735096|412200 |14000      |14000        |
|4735096|414200 |15000      |15000        |
|4733572|413800 |25000      |25000        |
+-------+-------+-----------+-------------+
```